# oracle bi publisher excel template report error- output failed

Tags: excel-2007, bi-publisher

I am using Oracle BI publisher. I created a Excel template report.
once generating the output for that report, I am not able to view the output in excel format. It throws error when I am opening the excel output file "The file you are trying to open, 'name.xls', is in a different format than specified by the file extension. Verify that the file is not corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file. Do you want to open the file now?" if I gave yes for this error, the page is opening with no records of output.

I even tried by generating the XML file and loading that file in the excel template, then view, I am able to see the Output. but when uploading the same excel template in the BI application and view the output, it generates the excel output, but throwing the above error and not able to see the output.

The template which i uploaded has **XDO_METADATA worksheet page**.
I saved my excel template in excel 97-2003 worksheet in .xls format.
My oracle **BI publisher desktop version - 11.1.1.7**
Excel version- **Microsoft excel 2007**
Add-ins in excel- **BI Publisher template builder for excel - type COM add-in**
solver add-in - **type excel add-in**

Answer (score 2):

We ran into this problem as well. On occasion it would just happen to one report, we would rebuild the excel template and that seemed to resolve the issue. However recently, our whole catalog was an issue. All the excel reports were getting the error, although they ran previously.

Turns out that the temp file on the application server was full. Our admin cleaned it out and restarted the BI service and that seems to have resolved the issue.